# using content type as JSON in form tag

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jsp-tags

I am having a page in JSP that needs to submit data to the server. I am just curious that whether by using enctype can we post this data in json format. As i have notice the browser by default encode it into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different things here. If you submit a form, changing the enctype is irrelevant, since the data is built by the browser from the form fields (name=value; etc.). So it won't be JSON anyway.

If you're not using a form but sending post data via an AJAX call, say, you don't have enctype available, you just pass the data you want, in whatever format the server expects.